# 'Missing ; before statement. (line 2, file "Code")' error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a chart dashboard from a Google sheet, I have used the tutorial but am getting the following error on line 2:

```
'Missing ; before statement. (line 2, file "Code")'
```

The start of my code runs like so:

```
function doGet() {
  vars ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(1POyMyUMGefIgt-I8TFgQEwN4XHH5nFgNr7BAnY39-Y4);
  vars data = ss.getDataRange()

  var organisationFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(0).build()
  var templateFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(1).build()
```

Any ideas why I cant run this script?

Thanks,

Comment: `vars` is not a keyword, it's being interpreted as an identifier. It wants `vars; ss = ...`. You might be looking for `var`.

Answer (score 1):

First, what is `vars`? I hope that it is a typo. That's why you get a error.
If you want to declare a variable, you should use `var` just like two lines below your `vars`.

Second, you don't have semicolons in the end of your code lines.
As far as I know, it is not obligatory. However, it is **highly** recommended.

Third, why isn't your string arounded by quotes?

Your code should look like:

```
function doGet() 
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1POyMyUMGefIgt-I8TFgQEwN4XHH5nFgNr7BAnY39-Y4');
    var data = ss.getDataRange();

    var organisationFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(0).build();
    var templateFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(1).build();
```

}